# Verilog - Can you `define a bit slice?

Tags: fpga, verilog

Can you `define` a bit slice in Verilog?

For example, is this possible:

```
`define opcode 5:3  // is this possible?

reg [ 7:0 ] a, b;

...

if ( a[ `opcode ] == someValue )  // a[5:3]

    doStuff

if ( b[ `opcode ] == someValue )  // b[5:3]

    doStuff
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `` `define `` almost any text you want. You would have to use  `` a[`opcode] `` with the backtick.

SystemVerilog gives you some other options.

The `let` construct declares a name for an expression.

```
let opcode = a[5:3];
...
if (opcode==someValue)
```

You can use a packed struct.

```
struct packed {
   logic [1:0] field1;
   logic [2:0] opcode;
   logic [2:0] field2;
} a;
```

Now you can refer to `a.opcode` as the same `as a[5:3]`.

Comment: shouldn't it be `logic [5:3] opcode;`? - Ah wait, no, it's packed. of course. I presume that order of definition matters. - Is there another kind of struct for doing what I just said? some absolute addressing?

Comment: Ah oops, added the backticks

Comment: @HarrySvensson, you could do it that way if you wanted. But if you do absolute addressing, you have to remember to access your fields with the absolute indexing. In fact, if you never plan to access the individual bits of your fields, that might be a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.

But it's probably cleaner and easier to simply break the register into fields using wires:

```
wire [2:0] a_opcode = a[5:3];

if (a_opcode == someValue) ...
```

How many different registers are you going to be extracting opcodes from?

Comment: Note that this solution only works for reading a_opcode, not writing to it. Most of the time, that is OK.